# I can't run my app in iOS 8.1 simulator

Tags: iphone, 64-bit, ios-simulator, xcode6

When I try to run my app in iPhone5s (8.1) simulator, I get the following error message. [image]

And following are the my Build settings :

[image]

I found that, this error due to 64 bit support not available for my app. So any one please help me. How to give 64 bit support to my existing app.

One more thing when I set Debug to NO of the 'Build Active Architecture Only', application run on iPhone5s(8.1) simulator without give me any error. Can you suggest me, Is my application has 64bit support or not??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your screenshot shows, you have set Valid Architectures to "armv7 armv7s" ...

You should set it to "armv7 armv7s arm64" (or just delete the overwritten value).

Also, make sure your deployment target is 6.0 or later (preferably 7.0 or later).

Comment: I want to give ios6 device support also, in this case what should I have to do? My app's current deployment target is 6.0.

Comment: Do exactly what I stated in the answer.  Set your deployment target to 6.0 and valid architectures to the default value (just delete your override) such that it contains "armv7 armv7s arm64"

Comment: Thanks  Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia, for make me clear about this thing.